# VFS : Cannot open root device "sda1" or unknown-block(0,0) error

Tags: kernel, embedded-linux

I have an SBC and it has a flash nandrive. I used to run it with kernel 2.6.18 but I am trying to upgrade my kernel to 2.6.33.7 or 2.6.38.8.

I have no problem with 2.6.18 kernel, it is stable and sees my nandrive as hdb.

2.6.33.7 or 2.6.38.8 see my nandrive as sda. (I am curious about that, why it does not see as hdb?)

My problem is 2.6.33.7 or 2.6.38.8 kernel sometimes gives "VFS : Cannot open root device "sda1" or unknown-block(0,0)". it generally works well but i take this error nearly every 20 try.

Is the problem related with grub?. I am using grub not grub2.
my filesystem is ext3.

Does anyone have an experience about that?

Edit: I may catch something which is, 2.6.18 using it 33 Mhz and the others try to use it 66 Mhz.

How can I make 2.6.38 kernel use 33 Mhz speed my nandrive?

Answer (score 0):

i solved this problem by disabling sata pata support on kernel.

maybe, rootdelay=120 or libata.force=1:pio4 kernel parameters works, if you have met with this kind of error.